# JsRender noConflict()

Tags: jsrender

I have found two threads related to the above topic:

- https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender/issues/74
- https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender/issues/26

However, the following snippet

```
  <script src="js/jsrender.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var myJsRender = $.noConflict();
  </script>
```

results in:

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

What I am trying to achieve here is to run JsRender regardless of whether

- jQuery and/or
- another instance of JsRender

is loaded on the very same page. Why: Chances are that another plug-in loads JsRender as well.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time of those issues, JsRender created a global `window.$` if jQuery was not loaded, but gave you a `$.noConflict()` method that told JsRender not to to override `window.$`, in case another library was using it.

But JsRender behavior has been modified since then so that it does not redefine `$` at all. Instead, if jQuery is loaded it adds methods to `$`, such as `$.render`, `$.templates`, `$.views.converters`... and if jQuery is NOT loaded, it creates a `window.jsviews` global, and uses that instead of `$` - so you have `jsviews.render`, `jsviews.templates`, `jsviews.views.converters` etc.

So for example, if you want to call the render method without knowing whether jQuery is loaded or not, you can write:

```
var $ = window.jsviews || window.jQuery;
// or window.$ = window.jsviews || window.jQuery;

$.templates(...);
$.views.converters(...);
$.render(...);
```

or if you don't want to use `$` - in case some library other than jQuery is using it, you can write:

```
var jsviews = window.jsviews || window.jQuery;
// or window.jsviews = window.jsviews || window.jQuery

jsviews.templates(...);
jsviews.views.converters(...);
jsviews.render(...);
```

I'll update those issues to include this information...

Comment: Sorry Boris, I was on vacation for a couple of days. Is there anything I still need to confirm/remove?

Comment: No, thanks - I edited your question to remove the EDIT section where you said it still did not work - since everything should now work correctly with my (updated) answer